# How to resolve E0658 error code on Anchor?

Tags: rust, anchor, solana, anchor-solana

I think I acidentally installed rust using`rustup` and `rustc` both which is causing this error! How can I fix this?

```
error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'bool_to_option'
  --> src/stake/tools.rs:31:18
   |
31 |                 .then_some(return_data)
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: see issue #80967 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/80967> for more information
   = help: add `#![feature(bool_to_option)]` to the crate attributes to enable

error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'bool_to_option'
   --> src/vote/state/mod.rs:679:40
    |
679 |         let root = (root != Slot::MAX).then_some(root);
    |                                        ^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: see issue #80967 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/80967> for more information
    = help: add `#![feature(bool_to_option)]` to the crate attributes to enable

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0658`.
error: could not compile `solana-program` due to 9 previous errors
```

Tried uninstall rust from brew but failed!

Answer (score 0):

Update your Rust version. This is a feature stabilized in Rust 1.62.0.

Comment: my rust version is already up to date `rustc 1.67.1 (d5a82bbd2 2023-02-07)`

Comment: @avdhesh.eth Are you sure you're compiling with this version?

Comment: yup but i think i've installed rust in two ways: using rustc and rustup

Comment: @avdhesh.eth How are you compiling the code?

Answer (score -2):

Just add `#![feature(bool_to_option)]` to the head of the file. It should solve the problem.

Comment: While this works, this is not a good answer. The proper solution is to update Rust.